# Ubuntu Server 20.04 hangs on black/blank screen during install on Intel NUC

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04, uefi, intel-nuc

I have a few Intel NUCs ([Intel NUC10i7FNH](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/188811/intel-nuc-10-performance-kit-nuc10i7fnh.html)) that I'm trying to get Ubuntu Server 20.04 running on. What I'm experiencing is that after the boot to the USB I see a screen that shows:

```
Install Ubuntu Server
Install Ubuntu Sever (safe graphics)
Boot from next Volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
```

Weather I choose `Install Ubuntu Server` or `Install Ubuntu Sever (safe graphics)` I end up getting blank screen that hangs forever...

**What I've tried**

- I've update the BIOS to the latest version
- I've made sure Secure Boot is disabled
- I've tried increasing the Video RAM after reading another post...
- **I've successfully installed Windows 10 and CentOS 8 without issue.**
- I would have tried disabling UEFI and going to Legacy BIOS... But Intel must have removed that feature
- I tried hard coding the Video output to HDMI instead of Thunderbolt
- I tried passing a few different kernel options to no avail.

  - `nomodeset` (safe graphics)
  - `acpi_rev_override=1`
  - `i915.modeset=0`
  - `acpi=off nolapic`

I'm pretty sure that this is a video issue. Because when I do a single press of the power button it's as if it's doing a graceful shutdown. So I think it's loading into the installer... I just can't see it. But I'm not 100% sure on this.

Any help would be great!

Thank you,

Cody Hill

**UPDATE 1**

Ubuntu Server 18.04 works perfectly...

**UPDATE 2**

Upgrading Ubuntu Server 18.04 to 20.04 works perfectly...

Output of `lspci -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=3840x2160 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2160
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:162 memory:6022000000-6022ffffff memory:4000000000-407fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**UPDATE 3**

Ok... I decided that it's possible that my 4K monitor that I'm using is the issue here... So... I grabbed an old TV that I have that is only 1080p and sure enough! The installer loads past the GRUB screen and I can do the full install. Very strange... I'm sure there is a way to fix this so that it'll support 4K or to signal to the monitor to only output 1080p. Anyone have a clue on how to do this?

After the installation is complete on the 1080p display. Moving the NUC back to a 4K display to load the console works fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I just ran into the same problem on a NUC 8 Pro (NUC8v5PNF), with a 4K Dell monitor connected via HDMI. The 'nomodeset' answer below did not work. Changing HDMI ports did not work. Switching to a smaller, non-4K monitor worked, though it's a little unsatisfying.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, in this case i was booting from a dell inspiron laptop with only intel integrated graphics, solution was to disable legacy rom aka disable bios and make it only use uefi.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm too late, but since I had the same issue with a NUC gen9, I'll post the solution I found after a lot of wasted time.

During installation, as soon as you get to the choice screen (install, UEFI..) choose install but press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the init and add `nomodeset` where there's `quiet` (I removed quiet too, because I want to see what's going on).

After that you can just install ubuntu, if you need you can redo the same thing in grub, but for my needs a ssh server was what I needed so I unpluged the monitor and lived happily ever after.

In any case this is an incompatibility ubuntu software side and they still haven't fixed it after 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Disable smart HDR on the monitor

Answer (score 0):

Asked a related question on ultrawidemasterrace sub-reddit, got a reply to try the DiplayPort port.

Tried connecting an Odyssey G9 49" to the USB-C port on the nuc, and viola, it boots and uses the entire screen.

https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/s/BhXGTfEk4Q

The poster of the answer has since delete the reply so I can't give credit

Answer (score -1):

Look at the specification.

Supported Operating Systems
Windows 10, 64-bit*

This NUC does only run Windows 10, no Linux.
I also run in this trap several months ago.

I could not get it run and sent the NUC back to vendor.

Comment: Wether I can call Intel and ask for support anc actually installing the OS are different things. This is just and x86_64 PC. If I were to grab a motherboard with this chipset and put this same Proc, Ram, @ SSD into it. It’s still just a PC. There has to be a way... Since CentOS 8 works. And it arrived from SimplyNUC with Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on it. (Which 4x of them still have installed.)

Comment: Well if you get it run you are lucky. I tried it really hard and gave it up after 3 or 4 days and several install retries including help from intel support.

Comment: Yeah. Works with a 1080p monitor just fine.